# Strongswan AUTH_FAILED

Tags: configuration, vpn, authentication, strongswan

I am trying to configure VPN server Strongswan and have a problem: the server always sends to the clients the following response:

```
IKE_AUTH [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
```

I've tried to change log level editing file `/usr/local/etc/ipsec.conf` to

```
charondebug="ike 4, knl 4, enc 1, cfg 4, lib 1, mgr 4, chd 4, job 4"
```

but nothing changed in log file and I still see the same error without any explanation.

What should I change on log-level or else to figure out what's wrong with the connection?

Comment: Are you checking the server log? You won't see any more in the client log, only the server knows why the authentication failed. See [the strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration) for information on the logger configuration.

Comment: @ecdsa Thx for your comment. Sorry that I put a lack of information but this log actually from server and this log has no a much information. Currently I am on the way to solve this problem. I patched source codes of strongswan (ike_auth.c) and add more logging at the every return AUTHENTIFICATION_FAILED point.